# in DataBaseHandler cannot be applied to (java.lang.CharSequence)

Tags: android, widget, searchview

I Have problem to creating SearchView Widget using Android Studio with error message:

> in DataBaseHandler cannot be applied to (java.lang.CharSequence)

My Code :

searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="search"
    android:searchSettingsDescription="search."


    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="2" >

</searchable>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.rifki.doaniatislam.AuteursActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_auteurs"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Points to searchable activity -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".AuteursActivity" />
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".QuotesActivity" />

            <!-- Points to searchable meta data -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
```

menu_quotes.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.rifki.doaniatislam.QuotesActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:orderInQuote="10"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

QuotesActivity.java

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quotes, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        //  SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search));
        // Configure the search info and add any event listeners
        //  searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
        //          .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                imageArry.clear();

                List<Quote> quotes = db.getAllQuotes(searchView.getQuery());
                for (Quote cn :quotes) {

                    imageArry.add(cn);
                }
                dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // Here u can get the value "query" which is entered in the
                // search box.
                return false;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                break;
        }


        return true;
```

DataBaseHandler.java

```
// Getting All Quotes
    public List<Quote> getAllQuotes(String limit) {
        List<Quote> quoteList = new ArrayList<Quote>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT quote._id, quote.author_name, quote.qte, quote.category_name,fav, author.file_name  FROM quote,author where author.name = quote.author_name ORDER BY quote.qte "+limit;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Quote quote = new Quote();

                    quote.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    quote.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                    quote.setQuote(cursor.getString(2));
                    quote.setCategory(cursor.getString(3));
                    // quote.setImage(cursor.getBlob(4));
                    quote.setFav(cursor.getString(4));
                    quote.setFileName(cursor.getString(5));
                    quoteList.add(quote);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }

        // return quote list
        return quoteList;
```

Comment: Does the error message occur while you are using Android Studio to display the page with the SearchView widget, or does it occur when the app is running?

Comment: Also, perhaps I missed it when quickly reading your code snippets, but where is the line of code that attempts to use `DataBaseHandler`, applying it to some text (a `CharSequence`) - since that is what the error message is complaining about?

Comment: this is the line of code:

Comment: This is the code that have a red color(searchView) on the QuotesActivity.java: List<Quote> quotes = db.getAllQuotes(searchView.getQuery());
                for (Quote cn :quotes) {

Comment: Can you check the error message again?  "... in DataBaseHandler" isn't a complete phrase, so it is not possible to understand what it is complaining about.  Is there another line before?  Something about `getAllQuotes`?  I'm not seeing `getAllQuotes` as a standard method, is that one of your methods?

Comment: ... and please answer the question in my first comment: **when** do you get the error message?  Is it in the log output **while you are running the app?**  **OR** does it happen **before** you try to run, while you are **editing** in the visual designer.

Comment: This in an error message when i try to build: Error:(233, 73) error: incompatible types: CharSequence cannot be converted to String